# Jersey REST webservice subresources not found

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

At first in my web server I only had one REST servlet. Something like:

```
@Path("/")
public class Controller {
  @GET
  @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_HTML })
  public Response get(@Context UriInfo info) throws Exception {
    ...
  }

  @GET
  @Path("resource1")
  @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_HTML })
  public Response resource1() throws Exception {
    ...
  }

  ...

 }
```

And the web.xml:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>xpto.mypack1;xpto.mypack2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But then I wanted to add some static html to the server, so I updated the servlet mapping to
    /rest/*

and the @Path directive of Controller servlet class from "/" to "/rest". Everything works fine but the sub-resources or methods of controller with the @path directive that stopped working.. ie:

- / works fine since I have an index.html page at root
- /rest works fine, it invokes the get method of my servlet
- /rest/resource1 returns 404 http code...

Any help? I already tried a list of combinations of / after and before each @Path directive, with no success... Many thanks

One update:

I used the trace util and got the following results:

for /[app-name]/rest (it works):

- X-Jersey-Trace-002    accept right hand path java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=/rest(/.*)? region=0,11 lastmatch=/rest]: "/rest" -> "/rest" : ""
- X-Jersey-Trace-003    accept resource: "rest" -> @Path("/rest") xpto.mypack.Controller
- X-Jersey-Trace-000    accept root resource classes: "/rest"
- X-Jersey-Trace-001    match path "/rest" -> "/application.wadl(/.*)?", "/rest(/.*)?"

for /[app-name]/rest/resource1 (it doesn't work):

- X-Jersey-Trace-002    matched exception mapper: com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException@4fd41dc3 -> xpto.myclass
- X-Jersey-Trace-003    mapped exception to response: com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException@4fd41dc3 -> 404 (Not Found)
  X-Jersey-Trace-000  accept root resource classes: "/resource1"
  X-Jersey-Trace-001  match path "/resource1" -> "/application.wadl(/.*)?", "/rest(/.*)?"

I hope it helps someone to help me..

Comment: have you tried setting path to `("/resource1")`

Comment: yep, I tried that, same result. I tried to debug to figure out what's happening and I found that the url part being compared to the pattern is only the part that comes after "rest". The part that ends in rest is considered "base url". This really puzzled me. By the way, I'm using tomcat. :(

Comment: Now I can't understand anything of this... I removed The slash from the controller @Path, making it @Path("") and everything works fine... Can anyone explain me why? :S

Answer (score 5):

If you define your servlet mapping as `/rest/*`, don't repeat `/rest` in the `@Path` annotation of your resources. I.e. all you need to do is keep the controller as is (in your question above) and just change the servlet mapping. The URL at which the resources are available is:

```
<application_context_path>/<servlet_mapping>
```

So, if you change the `@Path` annotation from `@Path("/")` to `@Path("rest")` and you also change the servlet mapping to `/rest`, then your resources would be available at:

```
<application_context_path>/rest/rest/*
```

Comment: Do you mean having "/rest" as servlet_mapping and @Path("/")? Or "/rest/*" and @Path("/")?